# Running Python Script From C# and Working With the Results

Tags: python, asp.net-core

I need to run a python script from a .net core web API repository to get the cluster of the current user and recommend the list of courses based on his ratings. (I'm implementing a collaborative filtering recommender system with the use of `sklearn.NearestNeighbor` to help with user clustering.

**List Course Repository**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Course>> GetList(int? userId, string name, ContextSession session, bool includeDeleted = false)
{
    var entity = GetEntities(session, includeDeleted).AsQueryable();
    var courses = await entity.Where(obj => obj.Id > 0).ToListAsync();
    SaveToCsv<Course>(courses, Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/csv/course.csv");
    var ratings = _dbContext.Set<CourseRating>().AsQueryable();
    if (!includeDeleted)
    {
        ratings = ratings.Where(obj => !obj.IsDeleted);
    }

    var i = await ratings.Where(obj => obj.Id > 0).ToListAsync();
    SaveToCsv<CourseRating>(i, Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/csv/ratings_Final.csv");

    ScriptRuntimeSetup setup = Python.CreateRuntimeSetup(null);
    ScriptRuntime runtime = new ScriptRuntime(setup);
    ScriptEngine engine = Python.GetEngine(runtime);
    ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/CB_RS.py");
    ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
    List<String> argv = new List<String>();
    argv.Add(session.UserId.ToString());
    argv.Add(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/csv/course.csv");
    argv.Add(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/csv/ratings_Final.csv");
    engine.GetSysModule().SetVariable("argv", argv);
    try
    {
        source.Execute(scope);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        var error = ex;
    }

    return await entity.Where(obj => obj.Id > 0).ToListAsync();
}
```

**The Python Script**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import operator


def get_rating_course_user(courses_path, ratings_path):
    course_df = pd.read_csv(courses_path)
    rating_df = pd.read_csv(ratings_path)

    #drop useless columns 
    #course_df.drop(columns_list, axis = 1)
    #rating_df.drop([columns_list], axis = 1)

    #merge 2 dataset on courseID
    df = rating_df.merge(course_df, on = 'courseId')

    # Get the ratings per course per user
    pvt = df.pivot_table(index='userId',columns='name',values='rating')
    #convert all NaN to -1.
    pvt.fillna(-1,inplace=True)

    #convert pivot table to sparce matrix
    spm = csr_matrix(pvt)  

    return spm, pvt


#returns a list of recommended courses according to similar user's ratings
def make_prediction(userId, courses_path, ratings_path, n_neighbors):
    recommended = []
    spm, pvt = get_rating_course_user(courses_path, ratings_path)
    # Creating, training the model
    nn = NearestNeighbors(algorithm = 'brute')
    nn.fit(spm)

    #testing the model
    test = pvt.iloc[userId,:].values.reshape(1,len(pvt.columns))
    distance, suggested = nn.kneighbors(test,n_neighbors=n_neighbors)
    for i in range(len(suggested[0])):
        x = pvt.iloc[suggested[0][i],:].values.reshape(1,len(pvt.columns))
        result = np.where(x >= 3)
        for j in range(len(result[1])):
            course = pvt.iloc[:,result[1][j]].name
            if course not in recommended:
                recommended.append(course)
    return recommended


#return dictionary {id_course: average_rating} of k courses having the best average_rating
def recommend_K_best_courses(recommendedList, courses_path, k):
    courses = pd.read_csv(courses_path)
    courseIds = {}
    for i in (recommendedList):
        ID = (courses.loc[course_df.name==i].courseId).to_string(index=False)
        rate = (courses.loc[course_df.name==i].average).to_string(index=False)
        courseIds[int(ID)] = float(rate)  
    sort = dict(sorted(courseIds.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:k])
    return sort


def main(userId, courses_path, ratings_path, n_neighbors=7, k=10){
    recommended_list = make_prediction(userId, courses_path, ratings_path, n_neighbors)
    return recommend_K_best_courses(recommended_list, courses_path, k)
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(userId, courses_path, ratings_path, n_neighbors=7, k=10)
```

I got the following error:

> unexpected token '{'

My current problem is running the python script, then using the result returned from the `main` method of the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a C# dev error, I opened the method main with '{' instead of ':'

```
def main(userId, courses_path, ratings_path, n_neighbors=7, k=10):
    recommended_list = make_prediction(userId, courses_path, ratings_path, n_neighbors)
    return recommend_K_best_courses(recommended_list, courses_path, k)
```